# Align parameters of bindParam() method in phpStorm

Tags: php, formatting, phpstorm

is there a way to auto-align parameters of followings bindParam() lines ?
Something from this :

```
$q = $bdd->prepare($query);
$q->bindParam("id_carte_joueur_base", $infos_carte['ID_carte_joueur_base'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindParam("level", $infos_carte['level'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindParam("id_membre", $infos_carte['ID_membre'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindParam("dribble", $infos_carte['dribble'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

to this :

```
$q = $bdd->prepare($query);
$q->bindParam("id_carte_joueur_base", $infos_carte['ID_carte_joueur_base'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindParam("level"               , $infos_carte['level']               , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindParam("id_membre"           , $infos_carte['ID_membre']           , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindParam("dribble"             , $infos_carte['dribble']             , PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Thanks !

Comment: Unfortunately No. I may only suggest to try and use Multiple Carets functionality and do this manually.

Comment: Why do you need this?? I could not see any use of this.

Comment: For a better reading. I find the second formatting more confortable.